# changing configuration value in spring-boot app with values of parameterized test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, parameterized-unit-test

I use this in my `MyService.kt`.
The `useXml` is read via `application.yml` and `application-test.yml`

```
@Service
class MyService (
    @Value("\${something.use-xml}")
    var useXml: Boolean = false
) {

  if(useXml) {
    // do this
  } else {
    // do  that 
  }
....
}
```

this works as expected.

but for the testing I want to use both variation:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyFunctionalTest {

    @Value("\${something.use-xml}")
        var useXml: Boolean = false

  //....
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(booleans = [true,false])
fun `do a parameterized test`(useXML : Boolean) {
    useXml = useXML // this is (of course) not setting the variations for `MyService.kt`
    if (useXML) {
      // test this  
    } else {
      // test that
    } 
      
}
```

I want a possibility where I can set the variable for the `application.yml` file, so both variations are tested.

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Using parametrized test for true and false is ... *very* generous/lazy... :) Better would be (as i understand) to do one test (class) with "normal test" profile and another (nested!?) test (class), which also activates "test" profile, but overrides this special property!? -> `@TestPtopertySource` has (one of..second!) highest precedence (s) in [spring boot props](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)(13.) ..for some reason ;)

Comment: Simplest (and 3rd highest precedence(12.)): `@SpringBootTest(properties={"foo=bar", "baz=buf",...}) ...@ActiveProfiles(...)`

Comment: also a nice way of doing it...
I will have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. You need to inject the service that you are testing and set its `useXml` value. In your case, it'll look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var myService: MyService

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(booleans = [true,false])
    fun `do a parameterized test`(useXML : Boolean) {
        myService.useXml = useXML // you have to set the value for the test case

        Assertions.assertEquals(useXML, myService.useXml)
    }
}
```

However, if I were you and have such a case, I'd go with two totally separate implementations of the same interface, if `xml` and the other format have something in common. In the end, you will have two classes (you need better naming for that):

1. `MyServiceXml`
2. `MyServiceJson`

Both this classes will be annotated will `@ConditionalOnProperty("\${something.use-xml}")` and they will be implementing the same interface.

That will be very easy to test, two different implementations, so two different test classes.

Comment: OMG. how can I have not seen that I'm able to change the value after autowiring it.
I have done that 100x before. but I was not aware, that I could control the set value.
Thanks a lot